# How to install KDE 4.3 on Ubuntu 9.04? (or how can I use konqueror 4.3 on andlinux?)

Tags: upgrade, kde, kubuntu, 9.04, git

I added the kubuntu jaunty backport deb in the sources.list file, the GPG key + done apt-get update and dist-upgrade etc…

Pick a question:

- Is there a way to update Konqueror 4.2.4?
- Where can I find the source of Konqueror 4.3 and how to build it?
- How to download [this git rev](https://projects.kde.org/projects/kde/kdebase/kde-baseapps/repository/show/konqueror?rev=v4.3.0)?
- Where can I find **4:4.3.1-0ubuntu1~jaunty1~ppa**?

Comment: why 9.04? any reason to use such an old version?

Comment: @uri you think i could upgrade [andlinux](http://www.andlinux.org/) ubuntu version?

Comment: using WUBI looks like a much better option, apparently andlinux has ceased development, or make room for a full installation.

Comment: @uri I need to run linux _inside_ windows.

Comment: Then i'd suggest you using A Virtual Machine

Comment: and to rephrase your question too.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought on this is running the latest kubuntu in a virtualbox in seamless mode - i.e. linux apps running on what appears to be windows.  I presume you've already considered this and discounted this route?

To answer your question directly...

My guess is that you will need instructions similar to [this](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=83036).

In summary:
you'll need a compiler, all the development packages to build against and QT4.

Then you'll need to compile using instructions such as

```
cd ~/kdebuild
mkdir build
cd build
mkdir kdesupport kdelibs kdepimlibs kdebase
cd kdesupport
cmake ../../kdesupport -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/where/you/wish/to/install/KDE
```

KDE themselves have a [wiki](http://techbase.kde.org/Getting_Started/Build) for this sort of stuff which you should familiarize yourself with.

From the KDE [Getting sources](http://techbase.kde.org/Getting_Started/Sources) guide it doesnt appear that KDE themselves regard 4.3 as current aka stable.  Thus you'll need to extract the code from git.
I've found some instructions [here](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=64&t=79832) on how to do this - I've just reproduced it for completeness

"Got this working. Key steps were realising that kdesvn-build had downloaded the non-KDE Qt version, so I did this, using Qt 4.5.1 for stability:

```
git clone git://gitorious.org/+kde-developers/qt/kde-qt.git qt-copy
git checkout --track -b 4.5.1-patched origin/4.5.1-patched
```

I put this under ~/kde/src in the qt-copy directory, then used kdesvnbuild (svn version) with "kdesvnbuild --nosvn qt-copy qca kdesupport kdelibs kdepimlibs kdenetwork" - after a bit of dependency finding, everything worked fine. As mentioned I used SVN 4.3.1 as the base, commands were:

```
cd ~/kde/src
svn checkout svn://anonsvn.kde.org/home/kde/tags/kde ... kdesupport
svn checkout svn://anonsvn.kde.org/home/kde/tags/KDE/4.3.1/kdelibs
svn checkout svn://anonsvn.kde.org/home/kde/tags/KDE ... kdepimlibs
svn checkout svn://anonsvn.kde.org/home/kde/tags/KDE ... kdenetwork
svn checkout svn://anonsvn.kde.org/home/kde/tags/kde ... upport/qca
```

"

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy answer but that seems rather troublesome. I am gonna try http://techbase.kde.org/Getting_Started/Build/Windows first and see if 4.3 is still available.

Comment: @Knu - I fully agree with you hence my comment about using VirtualBox in seamless mode.  To build on Windows, you'll probably need similar git clone and svn checkout statements to get the code tagged as 4.3 as above.  Good luck.

Comment: I am postponing this. You are getting the bounty for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

[Cooperative Linux](http://www.colinux.org/?section=home) is the first working free and open source method for optimally running Linux on Microsoft Windows natively. More generally, Cooperative Linux (short-named coLinux) is a port of the Linux kernel that allows it to run cooperatively alongside another operating system on a single machine. For instance, it allows one to freely run Linux on Windows 2000/XP/Vista/7, without using a commercial PC virtualization software such as VMware, in a way which is much more optimal than using any general purpose PC virtualization software.

- Version: 0.7.9 Release date: April 9,
  2011 Supported architectures:
  Intel-compatible 486 and above
- Supported operating systems (only 32 
  bit): Windows 2000/2003/2008 Windows 
  XP Windows Vista/7 Linux 2.6.x
- Supported guest Linux kernel
  versions: (Usable on mostly
  distributions with 2.6-kernel
  support)
- 2.6.25.20
- 2.6.26.8
- 2.6.33.7

[coLinux FAQ](http://colinux.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ)

Comment: I need to know first if Ill be able to update kdebase from 4.1 to 4.3 on the Fedora 10 image. I might end up with the same problem.

Comment: i believe it can be a problem, this is not a regular Linux installation. it's  a port of the kernel that runs alongside windows.

Comment: which is why i suggested the use of a VM